# Connecting Vertices

Tags: modeling

What is the correct option and procedure to connect 2 vertices and thus obtaining an edge line between them?

Here is a photo of what I am modeling in the hopes to obtain a base for the modeling of this crossguard end.

[image]

As you can see when I click vertex/connect vertex path or connect vertex pairs, blender gives me an invalid selection.
When I click vertex/new edge line from vertices a line connect the vertices but it does not appear to be a solid line on which I can work and I do not know its proper function.

Again thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hello :). To connect two free floating vertices press **F**. To connect vertices across a polygon press **J**. To connect two edge loops go to *Edge->Bridge edge loops*. Don't worry, we've all been there :).

Comment: I don't think you can connect them all at once though, you'd better re-extrude from the faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer covering the basics:

1) Connecting free floating vertices
*Vertex->New edge/Face from vertices*
Shortcut: <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

2) Connecting vertices across a face
*Vertex->Connect vertex path*
Shortcut: <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

3) Conecting two edge loops
*Edge->Bridge edge loops*
Note: Your loops need to be a part of one object.

[image]

Comment: THANKS very much for this basic lesson. Thanks to you I have managed not only to connect the vertices I showed but to build the whole skeleton section of the referred crossguard edge.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ronin074 Happy to help :).  You can now mark the question as answered.